# Update user in AD B2C using Microsoft Graph API (error 400 bad request)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have collection of users in AD B2C and now using Graph API I want to update one of the custom attributes of user, but constantly I have error `400 Bad Request`

This is my code

```
const test = [
      { client: 'john', status: 'confirmed' },
      { client: 'ema', status: 'rejected' },
      { client: 'melissa', status: 'pending' },
      { client: 'alice', status: 'pending' },
      { client: 'richard', status: 'pending' }
    ]
    const options2 = {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ extension_{applicationID}_Clients: JSON.stringify(test) })
    }
    fetch(
      'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/' + decoded.oid,
      options2
    )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log('result update user', result)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
```

This is the response

```
[Symbol(Response internals)]: {
 url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userID}',
    status: 400,
     statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
   counter: 0
   }
 }
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help to solve this problem.
I suppose body is the problem but I'm not sure where exactly.

EDIT: I'm saving stringfied array into users object

Comment: Could you please share what is in the response Message?

Comment: The problem was in length of array... max length of custom attribute is 256 characters...so if it is bigger I'm getting this message... I suppose that Microsoft doesn't support some custom length?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tested updating a custom attribute in B2C for a user using Graph API and it worked for me. Let me share the steps:

1. Create a custom attribute in B2C under User attributes blade:
   [image]
2. Now in order to update/patch a user with custom attribute, you need to use the following convention `extension_appIdOfB2CExtensionApp_CustomAttributeName`. Make sure the appId of the B2C Extension app has no **hypens** when when you use it with the convention `extension_appIdOfB2CExtensionApp_CustomAttributeName`. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow#using-custom-attribute-with-ms-graph-api).
3. I used Postman and made a PATCH call and updated the user custom attribute for the B2C user.
   [image]
4. Used the GET call and listed the user attributes and found the newly added custom attribute in the user profile:
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation... problem was in length of array, max custom attribute length is 256 characters, so I was getting message 400 bad request.... do you know is any possibility to extend 256 characters to more characters?

Comment: Can you point out the array in question here?